# Can a single activity cause delay in first load?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm pretty new to android development and was reading about fragments and their profits, but reading about fragment's lifecycle, I understood that "All fragments will be created when the host activity is created, All goes to start state when the host activity goes to start state and ..." , in return when working with multiple activities, each start independently.

now the question I came with is that :

> Due to fragment's lifecycle behavioral, would it cause a big delay at the starting of an app when too many fragments (let's say more that 20) exist in the activity?
>
> Is it suggested to use single activity app when the app has a complex structure which leads to creation of multiple fragments?

Comment: I use Single Activity patterns for my apps. I have apps with more than 20 fragments and there is not any noticeable delay in loading activity. The fragment creation and usage must be correct and optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test and logging I realized that in special case of using Navigation, not all the fragments are loaded at the same time but only those are required, for example in my case I do only have one fragment which is handled by a navigation, then when the activity runs only the Home Fragment is created, started and resumed not any other fragments, so not only this doesn't cause delay but it increase overall app performance as fragments are much less heavier than activities . So I suggest using Single Activity App along with navigation